# Rails titleize results in "incompatible encoding regexp match"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

My rails app is giving an ActionView::Template::Error with the message:

> incompatible encoding regexp match (ISO-8859-1 regexp with UTF-8 string)

The following code triggers this error when the `titleize` call takes place for the Chinese string **返回**. (`xxd` gives `e8bf 94e5 9b9e` for these two characters.)

```rb
<%= link_to t(:back).titleize, records_path %>
```

This does *not* raise an error in my workstation, only on my server.

How can I work around this? What's the cause?

Comment: Ha, interesting. Is that all the error message is showing?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but what ruby version are you ?

Comment: @JoelBlum whoops! I copy-pasted the wrong text. I've corrected the error message above. I'm on ruby 2.6.6 and Rails 6.1.3

Comment: Could you try config.encoding = "utf-8" in your application.rb?

Comment: @JoelBlum alas, it made no difference

Comment: did you create any custom inflections (config/initializers/inflections.rb) ?

Comment: I haven't created any custom inflections @LamPhan. (In fact, this works on my workstation but not on the server.)

Comment: it's strange, that error clearly fall into the scenario `a ISO-8859-1 string =~ /a UTF-8 regexp/` or vice versa, now suppose there's an accident on your server that lead to the `yml` file is saved as `ISO-8859-1`, the thing is both `ISO-8859-1` and `UTF-8` are compatible with `ASCII` (that mean no error), as you said that error happen on the `titleize` method and i dont find any  `UTF-8 regexp` related to that method, all regexp are `ASCII regexp`, except one case that your source code has a custom `inflections` that map to a `UTF-8 regexp`.

Comment: @LamPhan just to clarify, the error indicates that the yml is producing `UTF-8` and the regex is `ISO-8859-1` and not vice versa. I don't know why the ruby file `activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb` is getting loaded as `ISO-8859-1`. I guess that trying to set `config.encoding = "utf-8"` in `application.rb` must happen too late in the boot order to affect the encoding used when the gems are loaded? (But my environment also has `LANG=en_US.utf8`.) Thanks.

Comment: And `Encoding.default_external` returns `#<Encoding:UTF-8>`

Comment: i can reproduce by adding a `inflection human rule` like: `ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect| inflect.human Regexp.new("a".force_encoding("ISO-8859-1"), Regexp::FIXEDENCODING), '*' end`, and `"返回".titleize` will throw exactly that error. So that i recommend you check again all your app dependency gems (and your source code), maybe there's `ISO-8859-1 regexp` some where ... remember that the default encoding of both Ruby and Rails  is utf8, so what you suspect that the source is loaded as other encoding is hard to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem and to solve this by moment I rewrite `titleize` method as follow:

`app/classes/string.rb`

```
class String

  def titleize
    separator = ' '
    self.strip.split(separator).map do |part|
      part.first.capitalize + part[1..part.size]
    end.join(separator)
  end

end
```